# How to customize token validation on IdentityServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-authorization

[image: OAuth flow]

As described in the above picture each API Call to the Resource provider (RP) with JWT access token RP ensures token reliability by asking from the IDP server, now I need to add my customization to check token reliability on the IDP side.

I Implement these interfaces in IDP :

1- ICustomTokenRequestValidator

2- ICustomAuthorizeRequestValidator

3- IJwtRequestValidator

and register them  by these methods:

1- AddCustomTokenRequestValidator()

2- AddCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator()

3-  services.RemoveAll();

services.AddTransient<IJwtRequestValidator, XaniisAuthorizeRequestValidator>();

and it is my expectation that when I call an authorized API endpoint on (RP) my breakpoint on one of these implementations Hits. but there is no hit on my breakpoints.
is there any other interface or service responsible for JWT token reliability check?

#### Update:

I checked my network using Wireshark. and I noticed that there is no request to the IDP server when there is a request on the RP server.
Is there any option to enable/disable Idp JWT token validation request (request #4)?

#### Update 2:

I found that there is a `/connect/introspect` endpoints on the IDP that can check the validity of JWT. now the question is this:
How can I Enforce my RP to check JWT token validity by calling this API? and is it a good approach to check JWT token?
[This is the link to the documentation of introspecting endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/introspection.html)

Comment: The code where the client makes connection to server needs to set a parameter indicating the connection completed.  Then your validate interfaces need to read the parameter.

Comment: it does not make sense, which client? which server? which connection?

Comment: Those are question for you to answer, not me.  If you have multiple client connecting to the service than your validator must be able to validate every connection.  So in the server you need to set a parameter for each remote endpoint that the validator can verify.

Comment: Answer to your UPDATE.  Same answer that I gave.  What is the validator validating?  You have to set parameters when the client connects so the validator has something to validate.

Comment: I think you did not get the point of my question. I am talking about request #4 between RP and IDP.

Comment: In my assumptions, RP sends a given bearer token by the client to IDP to check that this token is really issued by IDP or it is just a fake token. I think if you provide more detailed description it will help more.

Comment: If it is a fake token where did it come from?  The question is how to prevent fake tokens.  First you need to make tokens random so they cannot be easily hacked.  Second you need to use HTTPS (not HTTP) so hackers cannot capture real tokens.  And third you need to use credentials (or authentication) so hackers cannot get into the site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247247/discussion-between-navid-pdp11-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the request to the IDP from the API (#4) entirely by providing the IDP public key to the API directly, like hard-coded.

Otherwise, the JwtBearer handler will by default query the IDP every 24 hours to get new keys/config, like how this picture below show:

[image]

If you use the JwtBearer library, I doubt you can have it to call the introspection endpoint for every request. However, there are a set of event handlers in JwtBearer that you can use to call the introspection enpoint manually on every request:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.Audience = "payment";      
    opt.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";

    opt.Events.OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        // When Authenticate is called
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        // When exceptions are thrown during request processing (invalid token...)
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnChallenge = context =>
    {
        // Invoked before a challenge is sent back to the caller.
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnForbidden = context =>
    {
        // Invoked if Authorization fails and results in a Forbidden response
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    opt.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
        // Token has passed validation and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated.
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Comment: thank you, I finally found that my RP request for JWKS from IDP in the first validation and save it and after that, it never calls IDP anymore, the code that you provide is interesting and I will check it.